# Version number didn't conform to three period-separated integers in iTunes Connect formatter

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I plan to submit a version number like 1.0.0.1 to the iTunes Connect,but after reading the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html),I still found some app didn't conform to the principle,e.g. [chrome](https://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/chrome-yougoogle-kai-fa-wang/id535886823?mt=8).

Comment: I don't know if apple differentiates between *should* and *must* in this case, the documentation states that the string should be in three parts, but maybe it is more of a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per apple's documentation the version number can only be in 3 parts, not 4:

> CFBundleShortVersionString specifies the release version number of the bundle, which identifies a released iteration of the app. **The release version number is a string comprised of three period-separated integers.**
>
> The first integer represents major revisions to the app, such as revisions that implement new features or major changes.
>
> The second integer denotes revisions that implement less prominent features.
>
> The third integer represents maintenance releases.